# How to prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (1-\frac {3}{n})^n=e^{-3}$ with the given fact that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac {1}{n})^n=e$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

**My Attempt**

I tried to use binomial expansion but it did not seem to help much. I know $e=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{r!}$ but taking its negative third power feels horrible.

**Important Note**

The limits are of sequences rather than functions.

Please do not solve the problem. Hints only please. Thank you!

Comment: It's worth trying to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1 + \frac an)^n = e^a$.  We can use $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+\frac an)^{n} = \lim_{am=n\to \infty}(1+\frac 1m)^{am}$.  (Although the negative value may or may not be an issue.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$1-\frac{3}{n}=\frac{n-3}{n}=\frac{1}{\frac{n}{n-3}}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{3}{n-3}}$$

Can you calculate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac {3}{n-3})^n$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try the change of variable $m = \dfrac{n}{3}$.